# setting up environment variables for aws hadoop ec2

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, java, hadoop

I've been following this book: **Hadoop in Action**

It gives a nice guide on how to start using ec2 with hadoop.

One of the first things that it says is to download the command line tools here:

http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=351&categoryID=88

Then it says to set these environment variables like so:

```
set JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_08"
set EC2_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Hadoop\aws\ec2-api-tools-1.3-30349"
set PATH = %PATH%;%EC2_HOME%\bin;%HADOOP_HOME%\src\contrib\ec2\bin
set EC2_PRIVATE_KEY = c:\ec2\pk-HKZYKTAIG2ECMXYIBH3HXV4ZBZQ55CLO.pem
set EC2_CERT = c:\ec2\cert-HKZYKTAIG2ECMXYIBH3HXV4ZBZQ55CLO.pem
```

My question is about EC2_HOME.

Even though I did set it, and I checked whether it has been set using the [set command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327495/list-all-environment-variables-from-command-line). It looks like it has been set correctly.

When I run the script: `ec2-describe-regions`

the output I get is:

> EC2_HOME is not set

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you restarted your Windows server and checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces from around the `=` sign. Also make sure there are no trailing spaces at the end of the line. You may also need to remove the quotes from the first two lines, although you should try both ways to see which one works best.

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_08"
set EC2_HOME="C:\Program Files\Hadoop\aws\ec2-api-tools-1.3-30349"
set PATH=%PATH%;%EC2_HOME%\bin;%HADOOP_HOME%\src\contrib\ec2\bin
set EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=c:\ec2\pk-HKZYKTAIG2ECMXYIBH3HXV4ZBZQ55CLO.pem
set EC2_CERT=c:\ec2\cert-HKZYKTAIG2ECMXYIBH3HXV4ZBZQ55CLO.pem
```

Comment: that did it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!